# 4th column is shown when specifying column-count of 3

Tags: css, column-count, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm trying to leverage the css 'column-count' in combination with CSS padding, and and I'm observing that if I specify a column count of 3, the browser renders part of a fourth column if content doesn't fit. as shown below

[image]

Here is a JSFidle -> [https://jsfiddle.net/w40jcykp/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/49Lfnao3/)

I'm seeing this in Chrome & Edge. is this a known issue, or is there a workaround for this?

Thank you kindly.

The CSS below.

```
.newspaper {
    column-count: 3;
    min-height:144px;
    height:144px;
    padding:20px;
    column-gap:10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: The height/min-height are causing it to wrap when the text needs more room than the three columns give.  I don't understand why this behavior is still happening if height is removed and you only specify a min-height -- the height doesn't seem to adjust. 

If you can get away with removing height and min-height, it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you've set a fixed height on your container. With the fixed height, the columns can't grow, so the rendering engine keeps making more columns to fit your content inside the container.

If you turn off `overflow: hidden` in your fiddle, you'll see that there actually a bunch more columns overflowing out of the side of your box. The `padding` just allows part of one of them to be visible.

The root cause here is *height balancing*. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts):

> The CSS3 Column specification requires that the column heights must be
>   balanced: that is, the browser automatically sets the maximum column
>   height so that the heights of the content in each column are
>   approximately equal. Firefox does this.
>
> However, in some situations it is also useful to set the maximum
>   height of the columns explicitly, and then lay out content starting at
>   the first column and creating as many columns as necessary, possibly
>   overflowing to the right. Therefore, if the height is constrained, by
>   setting the CSS height or max-height properties on a multi-column
>   block, each column is allowed to grow to that height and no further
>   before adding new column. This mode is also much more efficient for
>   layout.

Since you've set the height, height balancing says that the browser will fix columns to that height, and will create as many columns as it needs to display your content.

You'll need to remove your fixed height if you want your columns to grow and flow correctly and obey your `column-count` property.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Unfortunately maintaining the height is crucial at this time. I suppose I could separate the definition of height from column as in https://jsfiddle.net/w40jcykp/3/. I find it odd that this would be acceptable behavior.

Comment: Thank you I've been searching for this stupid fix for around 2 hours.